# Header of UITableView can't work with UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want header of the table view to blink, but it not working.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        0.3, delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat,
        animations: { headerView.alpha = 0 },
        completion: nil)

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: Do you see the headerView ? Or it is empty view?

Comment: i suppose animation works only after view has added on super view, this delegate method is asking for view and not yet added on tableview, thats why it is not animating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true);` before invoking the animation like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        0.3, delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat,
        animations: { headerView.alpha = 0 },
        completion: nil)

    return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try do this with timer, this issue may be resolve

Answer (score 0):

Try moving animation block to **willDisplayHeaderView** delegate method of table view, it will work

*Swift 3*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0,
                options: UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat,
                animations: { view.alpha = 0
            },
                completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't animate since view hasn't been added to superview. Try it after table reloads:

```
let headerView =   tableVIew.headerView(forSection: 0)
UIView.transition(with: tableVIew, duration: 2, options: [.repeat], animations: {
          headerView?.alpha = 0
        })
```